# Why is method overwriting subscribe action?

Tags: c#, blazor, reactive-programming, blazor-server-side

I'd like to understand why `SayHello` method in Razor component is overwriting subscribe event. I'm new to Reactive Extensions and I'm having trouble with the paradigm shift of push programming.

When I step through the code I didn't expect the outcome.

I have the website pulled up on 2 different computers.

The first thing that gets hit is the `SayHello` method in Razor component and then the subscribe handler runs 4 times. I figured the subscribe method would set message variable for both.

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using ClassLibrary1

@inject Class1 _x;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<p>@message</p>

<button type="button" @onclick="SayHello" class="btn btn-primary">Say Hello</button>

@code {
    string message = "";

    void SayHello()
    {
        message = _x.SayHello();
    }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _x.Notifier.Subscribe(x => {
            message = x;
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Class1

```
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private Subject<string> _notifier;

        public IObservable<string> Notifier { get { return _notifier; } }

        public Class1()
        {
            _notifier = new Subject<string>();
        }

        public string SayHello()
        {
            _notifier.OnNext("someone called SayHello");

            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not conversant with `Reactive Extensions`, but I can explain why the messages are different.

On the page where you click the button you are assigning the value to `message` twice.

Within the callback assigned to the subscription:

```cs
        _x.Notifier.Subscribe(x => {
            message = x;
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
```

And in the UI event:

```cs
    void SayHello()
    {
        message = _x.SayHello();
    }
```

Everything is synchronous:

1. The callback gets called and sets `message` to "Someone called SayHello".
2. You queue a render.
3. `_x.SayHello()` returns and sets `message` to the returned value "Hello"
4. `SayHello()` completes and the UI handler queues a render, which doesn't happen as there's already one queued.
5. The Renderer gets time to service it's queue, runs the render fragment, and renders the component based on it's current state.

The component render fragment has a tracking mechanism built in so  `StateHasChanged` can detect if an instance is currently queued.

You can call `StateHasChanged` as many times as you like.  The render fragment can only be run when the Renderer gets time on the Synchronisation Context.  That only happens if the current process yields or completes.